# Release Files not Found for Eoan security and eoan updates while on focal

Tags: apt, 20.04, 19.10

So whenever I run `sudo apt update` I get the following output:

```
    Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
    Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    Ign:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                                                                                                                                                           
    Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                               
    Hit:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                           
    Hit:9 https://debian.neo4j.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                            
    Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                           
    Err:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release                                                                                                                                      
      404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
    Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                      
    Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release                                                                                                                                                      
      404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80] 
    Hit:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                                                                                                                                            
    Hit:15 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                                                        
    Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
    Ign:17 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal InRelease
    Get:18 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal Release [1,838 B] 
    Reading package lists... Done     
    E: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' no longer   has a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now my Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS which is focal so I'm wondering firstly why are there eoan related repositories? Secondly, how would I go about fixing this error. I had eoan before as the first linux distribution I installed on my machine which I then updated to 20.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: During a correct upgrade procedure, the *eoan* get replaced by the *focal* upgrades.  My guess is (1) you didn't use a standard Ubuntu upgrade procedure, or (2) you re-added them yourself post-upgrade because you wanted a package that isn't available any longer in 20.04 (a number of things have now gone EOL in 2019, python2, Qt4 etc but I'm using them only as example).   I see it only as user done; someone with `sudo` rights, I'd just remove the *eoan* sources (rather than re-point them at *old-releases*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to resolve this would be to remove "eoan" repositories from the updater.

1. Open "Software & Updates"
2. Uncheck unnecessary repositories

[image: Software & Updates]

From here `apt` will update itself and you should be good.